# Question about libdrm and GPU device drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, gpu, drm

[An article](http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/06/the-linux-graphics-stack/) summarizes the steps involved in 3D rendering with OpenGL in this way:

> 1. Your program starts up, using “OpenGL” to draw.
> 2. A library, “Mesa”, implements the OpenGL API. It uses card-specific drivers to translate the API into a hardware-specific form. If the driver uses Gallium internally, there’s a shared component that turns the OpenGL API into a common intermediate representation, TGSI. The API is passed through Gallium, and all the device-specific driver does is translate from TGSI into hardware commands,
> 3. libdrm uses special secret card-specific ioctls to talk to the Linux kernel
> 4. The Linux kernel, having special permissions, can allocate memory on and for the card.
> 5. Back out at the Mesa level, Mesa uses DRI2 to talk to Xorg to make sure that buffer flips and window positions, etc. are synchronized.

I don't understand step 3. In step 2, the device driver for GPU, which is in kernel space, produces "hardware commands". Then these hardware commands are given to libdrm which is in user space?! I thought that the device driver interacts directly with the GPU itself. What is the role of libdrm here?

Comment: step 2 is not talking about kernel driver of your GPU, but mesa driver (OpenGL *implementation*) in user space. (I think hardware commands mean like which ioctl to call, and what params are passed with the ioctl, something like that.) Generally speaking ioctl is the way to instruct the kernel to do something specific from the userspace. (For example, `blkdiscard` in util-linux is used to issue ioctl to the kernel. The kernel then generates discard requests as per the ioctl, which are then "translated" into SCSI UNMAP commands or so.)

Comment: @TomYan, you mean there are two kinds of drivers for each video card: one loaded in kernel and one in user space?

Comment: That's a way to put it, I suppose. Note that graphical APIs like OpenGL and Vulkan are...APIs. What I mean is, the fact that they exist just mean from the user/program point of view you can use more or less "the same thing" to tell your GPU to do things for you/it. Once you look through "surface" (the API/language/spec), its implementation is still vendor/GPU-specific. I suppose because of that, you can call it a (DRI) "driver".

Comment: @TomYan, thanks, but I'm totally confused! Suppose the graphics quality is bad on my laptop, then I find a proprietary device driver, install it, and the graphics becomes excellent. How did it happen? I think the new device driver is loaded by kernel into kernel space and Mesa interacts with it via an interface. Am I correct?

Comment: Proprietary driver often includes both a kernel driver and its own OpenGL implementation. For example, the nvidia driver does that (which is why there's this thing called libglvnd). (I am not entirely sure but apparently it does not make use of libdrm.) AMD these days have only one kernel driver for modern GPUs. Its proprietary driver only offer replacement of user space stuff. In the case you mentioned, probably you are talking about an nvidia card, and the "in-tree" kernel driver, namely nouveau, only provide really basic support (if any at all, to e.g. new cards).

Comment: @TomYan, ok, suppose we have an OpenGL library in user space and a device driver, either proprietary or free, installed by us and loaded into kernel. What I'd like to know is the role of DRM and libdrm. Why do they exist at all?

Comment: To be frank, I don't know that much about graphical stuff, but it seems that DRM is somewhat like a sound server (like PulseAudio / JACK; but implemented in the kernel) equivalent in the rendering world. (But of course, in terms of rendering there's probably nothing like sound mixing. It's more about queuing instructions or so, I guess.) I have nothing to offer but the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager), heh.

Comment: @TomYan, thanks for your time and generosity.